# Property does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Client model that hasMany Appointment models. And an Appointment belongs to a Client. I am trying to return results that show me the client's name as well as their list of appointments on an index blade. Here is my code so far:

Client Model

```
public function appointment()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class);
}
```

Appointment Model

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
```

Controlller

```
$clients = Client::with('appointment')->get();

        //dd($clients); 
        return view('scheduler')->withclients($clients);
```

Blade

```
@foreach($clients as $client
{{ $client->name }}
{{ $client->appointment->id }}
@endforeach
```

How can I print $client name and their list of appointments? I have tried other help regarding this issue but I am not clear where I am going wrong.

Comment: You miss a paranthese on the `@foreach` line. Furthermore, how you came up with the `withclients()` function. How does it look like? You can pass values to a view through `return view('..')->with(compact("clients"));`

Answer (score 0):

So you relationship is a One-To-Many relationship. You have a lot of `appointments` then.

You can iterate over the clients list first and in the inner loop over the appointments:

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
{{ $client->name }}
    @foreach($clients->appointment as $appointment)
        {{ $appointment->id }}
        {{ $appointment->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Anyway, it might be easier to go over the `appointment` model, because it's in relation to exactly one client:

```
@foreach(Appointment::all() as $appointment)
    {{ $appointment->name }}
    {{ $appointment->client->name }}
@endforeach
```